# using onclick function to store CSV file to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, csv

`<i>`i would like to ask how do i store CSV file to database after i upload from html form.
i had tried to use onclick to store CSV file to database and it work. but at the same time i need to validate other fields in the form but i cannot make it using onclick function. in my project i integrate javascript with my php code and i know this cannot be done. can anybody help me to solve the problem? i jest need to store the csv file into database and validate other fields.

`

```
<?php  
require_once "lib/base.inc.php";
?> 
<script>
function checkmail(){
var subject = document.getElementById('subject').value;
var message = document.getElementById('message').value;
var csv = document.getElementById('csv').value;

if(empty(subject)){
alert("Subject is required.");
}
else if(empty(message)){
alert("Message is required.");
}
else if(empty(csv)){
alert("CSV file is required.");
}

else{
<?php

    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
    $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

    //loop through the csv file and insert into database 
    do { 
        if ($data[0]) { 
            $record['contact_first'] = $data[0];
            $record['contact_last'] = $data[1];
            $record['contact_email'] = $data[2];
            $record['status'] = 0;

            $oAdminEmail->insertQueEmail($record);
            } 
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")); 

    ?>; 
}
}
</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> 
<title>Import a CSV File with PHP & MySQL</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1"> 
  Subject : <br/>
  <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject"/> <br/>
  Choose your file: <br /> 
  <input name="csv" type="file"id="csv"/> <br/>
  Content : <br/>
  <textarea name="message" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea><br/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="checkmail()"/> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add an `accept=".csv"` attribute to the `input`.

```
<input type="csv" name="file" id="csv" accept=".csv">
```

I have tried your code and I found that I could upload any type of file. Since your code cannot be run with alert message using JavaScript. Therefore, the alternative way is you add `accept` to filter only particular file format will be display to avoid the unnecessary error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Use HTML5 required attribution to validate the form fields

```
<form action="javascript:checkmail();" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1"> 
  Subject : <br/>
  <input type="text" name="subject" required id="subject"/> <br/>
  Choose your file: <br /> 
  <input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" accept=".csv" required/> <br/>
  Content : <br/>
  <textarea name="message" cols="50" required rows="10"></textarea><br/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick=""/> 
</form>
```